# Complicated SAS Loop & Permutation Problem: Need to Calculate # of Days Between All Date Variables and Find Set That Matches Criteria

Tags: loops, sas, permutation, datediff, sas-macro

I have a wide dataset with 6 dates and 6 types. The dataset has between 2 - 4 million rows so I need the most efficient way to do this. Each type number corresponds to the date number. I need to compare each date and type to each other (2 at a time) and find the **earliest** date that these requirements are met:

**Criteria**

If both types = P, the difference between the dates must be 17 or more.

All other combinations must be 24 or more days apart

I have to find the **earliest** date match. So in my example, my "have" dataset has all 6 entries. My want dataset has the earliest two dates that meet my criteria which are 2 & 4. I can calculate this manually but can't figure out how to do it in SAS. I would love to have this in some sort of iterative macro program instead of taking up hundreds of lines of code.

**My logic on paper**

1. Calculate # of days between each admin_date (all permutations)
2. Ignore any that are not at least 17 days apart
3. Among those that are >= 17 and <24, check to see if both types are P. If so, take the combination with the earliest 2nd date.
4. If not, check those that are >= 24. Take the combination with the earliest 2nd date.

My calculations for Day Differences Between:

1 & 2: 1 day (ignore, less than 17)

1 & 3: 7 days (ignore, less than 17)

1 & 4: 18 days (ignore, not both P)

1 & 5: 20 days (ignore, not both P)

**1 & 6: 34 days (consider, ge 24)**

2 & 3: 6 days (ignore, less than 17)

**2 & 4: 17 days (consider, ge 17, both P)**

**2 & 5: 19 days (consider, ge 17, both P)**

**2 & 6: 33 days (consider, ge 24)**

and so forth

**Among all of the sets that met the criteria: 1 and 6, 2 and 4, 2 and 5, 2 and 6. 4 is the earliest so that's what I want.**

```
data have;
input person $
      admin_date1 : ?? mmddyy10.
      admin_date2 : ??mmddyy10. 
      admin_date3 : ?? mmddyy10.
      admin_date4 : ?? mmddyy10.
      admin_date5 : ?? mmddyy10. 
      admin_date6 : ?? mmddyy10.
      type1 $      
      type2 $      
      type3 $     
      type4 $   
      type5 $   
      type6 $;
format admin_date1 mmddyy10.
      admin_date2 mmddyy10. 
      admin_date3 mmddyy10.
      admin_date4 mmddyy10.
      admin_date5 mmddyy10. 
      admin_date6 mmddyy10.;
datalines;
JohnDoe 01/12/2021 01/13/2021 01/19/2021 01/30/2021 02/01/2021 02/15/2021 M P M P P J
;
run; 



data want;
input person $
      admin_date1 : ?? mmddyy10.
      admin_date2 : ??mmddyy10. 
      type1 $      
      type2 $      
;
format admin_date1 mmddyy10.
      admin_date2 mmddyy10. 
;
datalines;
JohnDoe 01/13/2021 01/30/2021 P P
;
run;
```

[have dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oub84.png)

[want dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8w21.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy if you transpose to long.  Basically just do a second nested `set` with a `point` that points to the next row and iterates over the other records in the same person.  It's not *super* fast, there are faster ways, but it's quite simple unless you have millions of rows.

```
data have_long( rename=(_admin_date = admin_date _type = type));
  set have;
  array admin_date[6];
  array type[6];
  do _i = 1 to dim(admin_date);
    _admin_date = admin_date[_i];
    _type = type[_i];
    output;
  end;
  keep person _admin_date _type;
  format _admin_date mmddyy10.;
run;


data want;
  set have_long nobs=nobs;
  if type = 'P';
  do _i = _n_ + 1 to nobs until (person ne _person);
    set have_long(rename=(person=_person type=_type admin_date=admin_date2)) point=_i;
    if person eq _person and admin_date2 ge (admin_date + 17) and _type = 'P' then do;
        output;
        leave;
    end;
  end;
  drop _:;
run;
```

Another similar solution, which works so long as `have_long` is able to be loaded into memory, is to use a hash table.  This might be faster, or might not be, depending on various details of the data.

```
data want;
  if _n_ eq 1 then do;  *declare the hash table;
    declare hash hl(dataset:'have_long', ordered:'a', multidata:'y');   *ordered ascending and multiple records per key is allowed;
    hl.defineKey('person','type');
    hl.defineData('admin_date');
    hl.defineDone();  
  end;
  format admin_date1 mmddyy8.;
  set have_long;
  if type = 'P';
  admin_date1 = admin_date;  *set the original admin_date aside;
  rc = hl.find();   *find the first match;
  do while (rc eq 0 and admin_date1 gt (admin_date - 17));  *loop unless we either run out of matches or find a valid date;
    rc = hl.find_next();
  end;
  if rc eq 0 then output;  *if we exited due to a valid date then output;
run;
```

Comment: I have between 2 - 4 million rows depending on the day. Sorry should've said that in the post. So I'm looking for the most efficient method.

Comment: If you need something more efficient, you need to add a LOT more information... it depends on a lot of things what the most efficient way to do it is.  How many people, how many records per person, how many "valid" records, etc. - way too many things matter here.

Comment: I'm getting this error message when I try the solution. 
ERROR: The POINT= data set option is not valid for the data set WORK.HAVE_LONG, the data set must be accessible by observation number for POINT= processing.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting - the above code runs fine for me.  That implies there's some difference in your storage ... is have_long a SAS datset? Is it stored in a regular base SAS 9 library?

Comment: Added a hash example, that might avoid the dataset type issue, and might (or might not) be faster

Comment: Thanks for the hash example! It works for type P but not for other types. But I think it's a great start for me to build on.